# How to make sure the service binding as quick as possible?

Tags: android, service

I have two application A and B. A is an application. B is an service. when A started, I will bind B service. and call a function in B, and I will start different UI according the remote call result. since bindService returned immediately, at that moment, binding is not finished.

Is there a grace way to handle this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend displaying a `ProgressBar` while the service binds and initialize the rest of the UI or functionality in the `onServiceConnected` callback since there is now guarantee how quick a service will bind depending on system performance.

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        mBound = true;

        // do UI and functionality initialization
        // OR simply service dependent functionality
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```